# Positioning a control to another control on a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form where user is supposed to put few 'ticks' here and there and when he finishes, I'd like to store locations of those ticks so I can restore them in exact alignment when the user opens the form again. No rocket science. I have a hard times with it, though. The form is a window of 788px x 574px and there's A4-size picturebox (pBox) on it (1035px x 1456px) - so the picturebox is a lot bigger and it scrolls when user is scrolling the form. The tick is other picturebox control (pb). I thought this code should store the locations:

```
calcX = pb.Left - pBox.Left;
calcY = pb.Top - pBox.Top;
```

And to restore the 'ticks' (check is object I keep tick data in):

```
pb.Left = pBox.Left + check.XPoint;
pb.Top = pBox.Top + check.YPoint;
```

It kind of work, but if user reopens the form in another window size, the tick is placed off the target. The same happens e.g. when user puts tick when pBox is scrolled all the way to the bottom. The problem is that pBox.Left/pBox.Top is 0/0 doesn't matter if the form is scrolled or not. I should take into account pBox alignment to the form, but I'm failing at it. Any help is appreciated. Take a look at attached pictures, the first is when pBox left/top is equeal to Form's beginning, the second is when pBox is scrolled to the right in the form, so it's Left/Top are probably negative to the form.

[image: pBox at form's beginning]

[image: pBox scrolled to the right]

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you just need to factor in the scroll offset when storing the position, probably with `AutoScrollOffset.X` (or whatever scrolling you use).

Comment: Why don't you simply get the Mouse Click Location inside the PictureBox? That's where the User clicked. The scrolling position is not relevant in this case, since the position is related to the Control's ClientArea. You can then set `pb.Parent = pBox`, then move it to a stored Location (since `pb` is parented to `pBox`, now its coordinates are the same as the Parent's). --- How do you know that the User clicked on one of the fake CheckBoxes? Did you store those locations somewhere? Or do you trust the User to actually do that? What if they miss the target?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I tried AutoScrollPosition approach and even though it worked in most cases, in some scenarios it was way off. I don't consider it reliable enough. Jimi, you nailed it, I have to coordinate pb to pBox. Normally I used this to take measure of where to put tick: `pb.Location = this.PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));`. If I make it parented to pBox, how should I measure the click point? `pb.Location = MousePosition;` is way off. I can't make it in mouse click event as pb is created in the event (so couldn't parent it to pBox earlier)

Comment: As to how do I know if user hit the target - honestly, I don't care. It's no survey or anything like that, it's just app to automate filling in some forms and printing them. Normally a guy would put those ticks on paper with a pen, and the next day he would have to do it all over again (most ticks would stay in present position, but some would change). This way he uses his previous form as a template that is already pre-filled

Comment: In the `pBox.Click` or `MouseDown` event, the clicked location is `Point clickPoint = (e as MouseEventArgs).Location;` (just `e.Location` in the `MouseDown` event). Create a new `pb`, set `pb.Parent = pBox`, set its Size and `pb.Location = new Point(clickPoint.X - (pb.Width / 2), clickPoint.Y - (pb.Height / 2));`. Finished. You may want to handle the Form's `KeyDown` event to allow `Keys.Delete` to remove the last `pb` added or the last one selected.

Comment: Jimi, I owe you a beer! It's working correctly no matter the window size and scrolling positions. Many thanks!